# pandas ranking based on a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need to ranking the group of event that repeat in pandas df. If met value 'retry' the next row's rank will be increased.
The perfect output will be:

| event | rank |
| --- | --- |
| init | 0. |
| call | 0. |
| retry | 0. |
| jini | 1. |
| init | 1. |
| call | 1. |
| retry | 1. |
| jini | 2. |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't quite seem like a rank, but you could do it like that:

```
# Shifting so the count increases after hitting a "retry"
df['rank'] = (df.event == 'retry').shift().cumsum().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   event  rank
0   init   0.0
1   call   0.0
2  retry   0.0
3   jini   1.0
4   init   1.0
5   call   1.0
6  retry   1.0
7   jini   2.0
```